# Corona SDK - email doesn't send

Tags: android, email, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to send an email using `native.showPopup`, but the email is never sent, below is the code:

```
function scene:createScene( event )
  function sendMail()
    local options =
    {
        to = "yourname@youremail.com",
        subject = "Game Result",
        isBodyHtml = true,
        body = "<html><body>Play Time: <b>10</b> <br> Score: <b>1</b></body></html>"    
    }
    native.showPopup("mail", options)
  end

  -- add some button to send mail
  submitBtn = widget.newButton{
      defaultFile="assets/submit.png",
      over="assets/submit.png",
      width=display.contentWidth/2, height=display.contentHeight/6,
      onPress = sendMail
  }
end
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
return scene
```

and this is the build.settings:

```
settings = {
    android =
      {
         versionCode = "11",
         usesPermissions =
        {
          "android.permission.INTERNET",
          "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
          "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
          "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        }
     },
}
```

I've tried in simulator and on my phone, but nothing is working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: *none is working*, any error ?

Comment: Does the chooser/or email app show when you press button? Do you press 'send' in email app? 'email is never sent' - how do you know?

Comment: @Raptor nothing happen, no error at all, any way i've solved the problem mate :D

Comment: @Melquiades any way i've solved the problem mate :D, just adding some validation below is my revision code :D thx

Comment: @r3d Unless I'm missing something, or you've changed something else, or there was another factor at play, the 'local mailSend =' addition doesn't explain why it works now...

Comment: @Melquiades i'm not changging anything ok, just change my code, are you who downvote my answer mate?

Comment: @r3d mate, as said, the change you did doesn't explain why it suddenly started to work, and probably that's why you got downvote from someone. Btw, I've tried your original code on my device, and it worked...

Comment: @Melquiades good, but in my device the original code doesnt work, its funny but i cant explain why my revision code working in my device and the old one doesnt.. fyi i'm using lua and corona for one weeks, that is why i cannt tell you good explanation :D

Comment: @r3d Sure, enjoy learning Lua/Corona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know why, but i just add some validation and now its work..
here the revision code i made:

```
function sendMail()
    local options =
    {
        to = "yourname@youremail.com",
        subject = "Game Result",
        isBodyHtml = true,
        body = "<html><body>Play Time: <b>10</b> <br> Score: <b>1</b></body></html>"    
    }

    -- add some validation
    -- and this is revision code
    local mailSend = native.showPopup("mail", options)
    if not mailSend then
        native.showAlert( "Alert!", "Mail cannot be send.", { "OK" })
    end
end
```

thx

Comment: how can i get downvote? can u explain why for you who downvote this solution?

Comment: I agree, this is not an answer. Its great that you post the fix that worked for you but it cant be the whole story. If you run the app now anf runs fine and you comment out the if block and remove the local  assignment and it no longer runs, ill be super-amalgamated.